# What happens if multiple users make a request in Blazor at the same time?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, frontend

I am literally just getting into frontend and Blazor and am making a simple web application that queries a database, based on data entered by the user. Since I'm using Entity Framework Core I have to be careful about database context transactions, namely there can't be two simultaneous transactions on the same dbcontext.

Since the logic that works with the DB and EF Core is in a regular class and method I wonder if two users click the button on the frontend at the same time, will this start two separate threads that will have two separate dbcontexts and everything will be fine or will both threads (I suppose it *can't* be only one thread, it's the 21st century) use the same dbcontext?

For clarity - I create/instantiate my dbcontext at startup with information from appsettings.json. I can change it no problem, I just need to know if I should.

Comment: What? Why can't you have two concurrent transactions? The database will sort that out and keep them atomic and isolated etc. You *are* using `TransactionScope` right? Although, yeah, EF isn't thread-safe, but you can just create a new context

Comment: @Charlieface, https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913

Comment: As I said, use a different `DbContext`. The database can handle concurrency.

Comment: @Charlieface, it appears we misunderstood each-other, because in my question I was *specifically* talking about the problem with a single DbContext. No, matter i think we got it, now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the DbContext is scoped within the controller. The simplest thing is something like:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction( /* params */)
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        // load and return or update and return data, 
        // preferrably projected ViewModels, not Entities
    }
}
```

Each request uses a separate DbContext. The main issues with this approach is that it is more difficult to unit test the controller in isolation, (Mocking a DbContext & DbSets are a pain) and it can be troublesome to pass around the DbContext for bigger workflows that you might want to spread out across different methods or services.

A recommended pattern is Dependency Injection /w an IoC Container such as what ASP.Net Core can provide natively, or others like Autofac. Here your controller accepts a DbContext or patterns like a Unit Of Work that wrap the DbContext, usually as a constructor parameter. From there it is up to how the IoC container is configured to "scope" the lifetime of DbContexts it provides. There are a number of options depending on the container but the typical ones are:

- Singleton - one instance for *all* requests. (Definitely not what we want for the DbContext since this would be sharing the same reference between web requests)
- Per Web Request - One instance per web request. (Recommended)
- Per Scope - Allows you to specify a scope boundary (smaller than the web request) and returns the same instance while within that scope.
- Per Call / Transient - Returns a new instance whenever requested. (Not recommended since entities coming from different services accessing a DbContext in the same web request would be associated with different DbContexts.)

Comment: Thanks and I agree with your statements, however the question is about what happens when multiple users send the same request to the server.

Comment: @user14092802 He said what you should do: new DbContext per request. Different users sending even the same request will run the code independently of each other, so you will then always have a new DbContext

Comment: Yes, the scope of the DbContext will determine what happens when multiple requests come in. Each request will be serviced by a worker thread handling the requestsor queued up for a free request thread. Using the simplest example this means each request, even for the same method, will get a dedicated DbContext. (safe). What you need to avoid is any sort of `static` scoped DbContext, (very bad) or caching/transmitting entities between requests. (gets messy)

Comment: @StevePy, ah-ha, each request services by a worker thread which, in turn, gets a DbContext depending on its scope is the exact answer I was looking for, thanks!